# Working with SerialPort´s DataReceived Event

Tags: c#, com, serial-port

Im trying to read the output of a device on a COM port on my PC.
Im wrote a C# program to do so.
Using PuTTY, I can see the output Im expecting from my device.
The problem is that the function `SerialPort.ReadExisting();` in my `DataReceived` function gives my a completely different string.
What is the proper way to read from a COM port using `SerialPort`?

Also, the strings I get from `SerialPort.ReadExisting();` are fragments of the string I sent to the device.

Below is the code that initializes the `SerialPort`.

```
    SerialPort port;

    void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data = port.ReadExisting();
    }

    void init_serialport(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (port != null)
        {
            port.Close();
        }

        port = new SerialPort( /* ... */ );
        port.BaudRate = 9600;
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;

        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

        try
        {
            port.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the ReadExisting method is using an encoding that matches the raw data being delivered?

Comment: You might also take a look at this thread, which seems to address your problem all-but on the head: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714533/how-to-apply-encoding-when-reading-from-a-serial-port

Comment: It says that the encoding used is ASCII, which I think is the right one.

Comment: Perhaps provide an example of "completely different string" and the expected string.

Comment: What I find confusing is that the returned strings are fragments of the string I sent to the port. Does that give you an idea of whats wrong?

Comment: Well, certain characters of a string may encode similarly even in different encoding sets, so that still suggests an encoding problem. Have you looked at the raw bytes yet? The raw bytes almost surely tell the tale.

Comment: The raw bytes are the ASCII codes of the chars of the string that I sent to the SerialPort.

Comment: Okay, so, if the raw bytes coming in are, in fact, the raw bytes that you're sending, I think that pretty much leaves the string encoding as the problem.

Comment: I dont quite understand why the string encoding is the problem. The device acts the way I excpect when I send data, but the data I receive is obviously wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, and if so, my apologies. Are you inspecting the raw data bytes your application is receiving, or the string that is being rendered? My inference from your original post is that you're looking at the *string*, which is encoded from the raw bytes. Hence my suggestion that we look at the raw data, not the string. If you've changed your program above to look at data, and you know the raw data bytes do not match, I'd have to suspect comm parameters.

Comment: To clear things up: I am inspecting the raw bytes I receive from `SerialPort.Read(byte[],int,int)` within the `DataReceived` event. Those bytes happen to be the ASCII codes of the characters I sent to the device which is not the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> the strings I get from SerialPort.ReadExisting(); are fragments of the string I sent to the device.

I'd have a look at SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold.

"Gets or sets the number of bytes in the internal input buffer before a DataReceived event occurs."

Answer (score 0):

I would first take a look at the Read method of the port object, look at the raw bytes and verify that they match your expectations, which would then narrow down the problem to the encoding on the conversion to string.

More information on this is provided [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714533/how-to-apply-encoding-when-reading-from-a-serial-port)

Answer (score 0):

You received fragments because SerialPort.Existing() executes and completes in less time then it takes for your sending device to send the entire string.

You need to repeat the call continuously or until you received the end of string character if the string has one.